# <sup> in a element with underline

Tags: html, css

Ive got a element with styling underline.

In the link there is <sup>TM</sup> element.

Is it possible to make underline at the bottom of all word cause right now there is a break in line and underline in sup element is higher.

Thank for help

Comment: Show us your code. Both HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<u>This is some text for Brand Name&trade; to test the error.</u>`

That works. I cannot recreate your error.

**EDIT**
Okay, my bad - I answered without using the `<sup>` element. If you're just using the Trademark (™) marker, it's better to just use the HTML expression for that, which is `&trade;` - use that directly in your text.

Regarding your question, you really have two options.

**CSS**

```
sup {
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

* you may need to adjust the `padding-bottom` value depending on your line height.

**HTML**

`<u>This is a Brand</u><sup>for a company</sup><u> and then some more text</u>`

---

or, Lollero's version (modified to work in line)...

**CSS**

`div.underline { display: inline; padding-bottom: 1px; border-bottom: 1px solid #222; }`

**HTML**

`<div class="underline">what'<sup>s UP</sup></div>`

Answer (score 2):

Guess this will not get noticed, but it's working on FF, IE8 and above, sadly not in chrome:

> font-size: 60%; vertical-align: top;

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the text to be underlined in outer element you can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/j2F84/1

HTML:

```
<div>what'<sup>s UP</sup></div>
```

CSS:

```
div { border-bottom: 1px solid #222; float: left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution to this problem (seems there's always a situation that requires some fiddling to fix).

For me I preferred to do it this way (works with wrap)

HTML:

```
<span class="u2">
  Registered<sup>&reg;</sup>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.u2{
  border-bottom:2px solid #666666;display:inline;
}
sup{
  font-size: 40%;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sLtkx2qe/